# Can't get PowerShell to read the * character

Tags: java, powershell

I'm a beginner in Java programming and while i was trying to create a calculator i've come across this problem: the powershell manages to read every character properly except for the asterisk, i've tried writing it in many ways: *, "*", '*' but it still acts as a wildcard character and not as a proper asterisk. How do i fix this?

Example: If I write

```
java Calculator 1 2 *

java Calculator 1 2 "\*"

java Calculator 1 2 '*'
```

none of these work and it always gets the asterisk as a wildcard character.

Comment: Try to escape it `\*`

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx) Powershell tip.

Comment: tried both \\* and "\\*" and it gives me a different output \System Volume Information but it still doesn't read it as an asterisk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not related to **PowerShell** per se, because it **passes `*` through - however, it does so *without quoting***, whether you use `*`, `"*"`, or `'*'`.

Therefore, the question is: **What kind of quoting of `*` does your *target* program require for it to treat `*` as a *literal* rather than as a glob (wildcard expression)?**

For instance, **if you need to ensure that your target command sees the `*` as `"*"`, you must use *literal* (embedded) double quotes:**

```
java Calculate 1 2 `"*`"     # `" escapes a literal "
```

or, using single quotes with embedded literal `"` instances:

```
java Calculate 1 2 '"*"'
```

Note that since Powershell doesn't recognize `\` as an escape character, using `\*` as-is would suffice to pass *literal* character sequence `\*` - unquoted - to `java`.

---

#### Optional background information:

PowerShell - unlike POSIX-like shells (in the Unix world) - does *not* itself automatically expand (unquoted) wildcard-like arguments such as `*` to matching filenames (it is up to the target commands to interpret such wildcards).

Therefore, when you call external utilities such as `java`, tokens such as `*` are *passed through*.

However, whether you use `*` unquoted or whether you quote it as `'*'` or `"*"` makes no difference in this case, because PowerShell, after it has performed *its own* parsing, *rebuilds* the command line, using (double)-quoting around the arguments only *if needed*.

Token `*` needs *no* quoting, because it has no embedded whitespace, therefore, all 3 variations of your command result in the exact same command line when `java` is invoked: something like `c:\path\to\java Calculator 1 2 *`

Therefore, the only way to guarantee that an external utility sees an argument as `"`-enclosed, for instance, is to make the `"` chars. a *literal* part of the argument, as demonstrated above.

Comment: @SashaToscano: My pleasure; I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the escape Character "\*" ?

For example:

```
java Calculator 1 2 \*
```

Comment: tried both \\* and "\\*" and it gives me a different output \System Volume Information but it still doesn't read it as an asterisk